# JBOSS admin console page

Tags: jboss-eap-6

My Boss Console is not opening. It is throwing below error.

"
Unable to redirect.
An automatic redirect to the Administration Console is not currently available, this is most likely due to the administration console being exposed over a network interface different to the one you are connected to.
To access the Administration console you should contact the administrator responsible for this JBoss installation and ask them to provide you with the correct address.

"

I started the jboss using below command.

> standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml -b 0.0.0.0

and also tried with below

> standalone.bat -c standalone-full.xml -b {Ip of server}

it is giving the same message.

Any suggestions

Thx
Muthukumar.S

Answer (score 3):

Change your Jboss configuration as below:

Step 1: vi /standalone/configuration/standalone.xml 
Step 2: Replace 127.0.0.1 with 0.0.0.0

```
<interfaces>
<interface name="management">
    <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
</interface>
enter code here
```

Step 3: Save and restart Jboos service

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `-bmanagement 0.0.0.0` to set the IP address for the management endpoint to listen on.